# gets all static members of namespace

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a class with static members.
I want to get a list of all the static members that their class is defined in the namespace "foo" and inherit from class "bar"

something like `list x= typeof(this).staticmembers.where(namespace == "foo");`

TRY1:

```
 var AllowedTypes = GetType().Assembly.GetTypes()
       .Where(x => x.Namespace == "XX.XXX.XXX")
       .Where(x => x.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(UserControl)));

    var StaticMembersOfAllowedTypes = typeof(MainWindowXX).GetMembers  (System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static ).Where(item => AllowedTypes.Contains(item));
```

this gives me a list of member infos, but I want the items themselves.

so I can do foreach item compare to another item.

Comment: You want to get all of the static `Type` in a namespace right?  Not all of the static members of any `Type` that are defined in a namespace?

Comment: I believe static types cannot inherit from others, so he may be wanting the static members of those types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this will do the trick. It's possible there's some typos, I couldn't test it

```
var list x = GetType().Assembly.GetTypes()
                    .Where(x => x.Namespace == "foo" && typeof(bar).IsAssignableFrom(x))
                    .SelectMany(x => x.GetMembers(BindingFlags.Static));
```

You may need to add `BindingFlags.Public`:

```
x.GetMembers(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
```

Comment: that have put me in the right track. but I seem to fail get the members themselves, only the memberinfos. can you help please

Comment: The Memberinfos are the representations of the members. What do you actually need? What do you mean by "members themselves"?